# Implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have made an implementation of [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm in Java, and am not certain that it is as efficient as possible.

I have looked at other peoples implementations on Google, and on this site, which raised concerns for me, as no one has taken a similar approach to me.

```
public class sieveOfEratosthenes {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int maxPrime;
        try (java.util.Scanner tempInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("What number would you like the prime numbers to be generated to?");
            maxPrime = tempInput.nextInt();
            tempInput.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Computing list...");
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int [] numberList = new int [(maxPrime - 1)];
        boolean [] isPrime = new boolean [(maxPrime - 1)];
        for(int i = 0; i < (maxPrime - 1); i++) {
            numberList[i] = (i + 2);
            isPrime[i] = true;
        }
        int maxTestNum = (int) Math.sqrt(maxPrime);
        int tempAns;
        for(int j = 0; j < maxTestNum; j++) {
            int temp = numberList[j];
            if(isPrime[j] == true) {
                temp = numberList[j];
            }
            for(int k = j; k < (numberList.length - 1); k++) {
                for(int p = 2; p <= numberList.length; p++) {
                    tempAns = temp * p;
                    if(tempAns > maxPrime) {
                        break;
                    }
                    for(int z = 0; z < numberList.length; z++) {
                        if(numberList[z] == tempAns) {
                            isPrime[z] = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.print("Prime numbers than are <= " + maxPrime + ": ");
        for(int n = 0; n < numberList.length; n++) {
            if (isPrime[n] == true) {
                System.out.print(numberList[n] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Execution time: " + ((stop - start) / 1e+6) + "ms");
    }
}
```

The issues I came across whilst creating it were:

- What is the best way of storing a list of numbers?
- Is there a more efficient way of generating a list of numbers, rather than just using a `for` loop?
- How efficient are arrays? Is there a more efficent 'version' of an array that could have been used to store/access data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way of storing a list of numbers?

Not doing them at all? It's both the fastest and the most memory-efficient solution.

And it applies perfectly to your use case as `numberList[i] == i+2` always holds.

> Is there a more efficent way of generating a list of numbers, rather than just using a for loop.

There are many ways to speed it up, but there's actually always such a loop. One trivial optimization is to ignore even numbers.

> How efficent are arrays?

It's the fastest storage when you access data either sequentially or by index. So concerning `isPrime`, it's the best what you can do (unless you want to trade speed for memory, then look at `BitSet`).

Concerning `numberList`, it'd be much better to drop it. Computing `i+2` is surely way faster than reading `numberList[i]`.

---

Now I have a question: How can you code be used? The answer is that

- not without user interaction
- not without reading the console
- not for task like [this one](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7)

How can it be improved: [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Luckily it's very easy to do in your case: Just extract methods (the IDE can do it for you):

- `readInput`
- `sieve`
- `printResult`

### Review

```
    int maxPrime;
```

Note that it's (usually) no prime at all.

```
    int [] numberList = new int [(maxPrime - 1)];
    boolean [] isPrime = new boolean [(maxPrime - 1)];
    for(int i = 0; i < (maxPrime - 1); i++) {
        numberList[i] = (i + 2);
        isPrime[i] = true;
    }
```

Drop `numberList`, use `Arrays.fill(isPrime, true)`.

```
    int tempAns;
```

You don't need it here.

```
        int temp = numberList[j];
        if(isPrime[j] == true) {
            temp = numberList[j];
        }
```

You mean, "in case of a prime, we really want that `temp` has the value already assigned and assign it once more, just in case".

```
        for(int k = j; k < (numberList.length - 1); k++) {
```

No need for parentheses here.

```
                for(int z = 0; z < numberList.length; z++) {
                    if(numberList[z] == tempAns) {
                        isPrime[z] = false;
                    }
                }
```

This makes your code very slow. You could do (possibly after some bounds checks)

```
 isPrime[tempAns-2] == false;
```

and save yourself a loop.

But actually you should simplify it so that you do just

```
 isPrime[tempAns] == false;
```

s saving two elements of a potentially huge array makes no sense. Btw., `tempAns` is a really bad name (even worse than`temp`). Call it `product`.

```
        if (isPrime[n] == true) {
```

Don't do it. All the following expressions are equivalent:

- `isPrime[n]`
- `isPrime[n] == true`
- `(isPrime[n] == true) == true`
- `((isPrime[n] == true) == true) == true`
- `(((isPrime[n] == true) == true) == true) == true`

Just use the simplest one.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is no need for an explicit Array of numbers.

The index you use to accesss the elements in the `isPrime` is the number you are testing.

To make it explicit instead of

```
if(isPrime[j] == true) {
     temp = numberList[j];
}
```

if you don't use the additional `numberList` you could rewrite it as

```
if(isPrime[j] == true) {
     temp = j;
}
```

Which saves you an access to the element array via index.

This would allow you also to write

```
for(int z = 0; z < numberList.length; z++) {
   if(numberList[z] == tempAns) {
      isPrime[z] = false;
   }
}
```

as

```
isPrime[tempAns] = false;
```

Some additional remarks about your code:

```
int maxTestNum = (int) Math.sqrt(maxPrime);
```

should be

```
int maxTestNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(maxPrime));
```

which saves you at least for each outer loop steps `2 * numberList.length` accesses to the arrays via index (i.e. `numberList[z]` and `isPrime[z]`)

```
int temp = numberList[j];
if(isPrime[j] == true) {
     temp = numberList[j];
}
```

seems to be wrong. You unconditionally assign `temp` the value of `numberList[j]` and afterwards you check for `isPrime[j] == true` and repeat that assignment.

Disadvantange of the suggested approach is that the `isPrime` array contains two additonal elements for the numbers 0 and 1. For the execution time this is usually is negligible - especially for big `maxPrime`s.

For your Questions

- The best way of "storing" the numbers is not to store them explicitly.
- No there is no more efficient way than the loop to fill an array with numbers - except to avoid it.
- Accessing the a primitive array via index is constant in time - no there is no more efficient data structure for this kind of access.

Answer (score 0):

`int [] numberList` is probably redundant.
AFAIK a standard implementation of the sieve needs only a boolean-array, as it is enough to store the information if a number is prime.

You have quite many (four) nested for-loops (3 with numberList.length, one  with Math.sqrt(max)), this is most probably too complicated/slow/not needed. A simple implementation (which are also on this site, for example [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7599/sieve-of-eratosthenes)) only needs two nested loops.

The complexity of your algorithm is probably not optimal. On a modern computer, a simple implementation of the sieve should be able to calculate the number of primes below 1 million or 10 million almost instantly. How long does it take for you?